# Asus Xtion on USB 3.0 - ROS-hydro - Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: xtion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a few weeks I want to use pro Xtion, the USB 3.0 ports. I tried in different version of Ubuntu and ROS, but it still does not work.
Currently, I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 (64 bits), and hydro ROS. The Xtion USB 2 works well, but when I go to the USB 3.0, I have the following message:

```
Image: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.1.0.41: Failed to open the USB device!
```

*Update :*

As mentioned in this [thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/54747/primesense-carmine-doesnt-work-but-asus-xtion-does-openni-launch-devices-connected-but-not-found/) I updated the driver used.
But now, even in USB 2.0, I have this message :

```
Image: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.1.2.1: Failed to set USB interface!
```

As mentioned [here](http://reconstructme.net/2012/10/13/asus-xtion-usb-3-0-hotfix/) I update the firmware of my camera, and it works on Windows on USB 3.0.

But unfortunately not with ROS ....

*Update 2 :*

I try to test OpenNi2 through the package in ros-hydro, when I run `rosrun openni2_camera openni2_camera_node`, I get the following message:

```
[INFO] [1378807167.725457003]: Device "1d27/0601 @ 3/3" connected

[WARN] [1378807167.728880859]: ~ device_id is not set! Using first device.
Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might causes loss of data ...
```

A little help would be appreciated....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/77651/asus-xtion-on-usb-3.0---ros-hydro---ubuntu-12.10/) by [Dyna](https://answers.ros.org/users/6566/dyna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2013-09-09

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-09-10**:
I know it's not much help but at some point I found an article that stated the firmware on the Xtion has a bug that makes it incompatible with the standards compliant implementation of USB3.0 in the linux kernel. I really hoped that somehow this would be fixed, but I am not optimistic about it.

**Comment by [Dyna](https://answers.ros.org/users/6566/dyna/) on 2013-09-10**:
Hello,
Thank you for your answer, is it possible to get the link to the article?

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-09-10**:
it was a year ago that I played with it last, so I'm afraid I don't recall the URL. :(  If you do get it working on USB 3 please update the ROS wiki and this question though :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After installing [ASUS' USB 3.0 hotfix](http://reconstructme.net/2012/10/13/asus-xtion-usb-3-0-hotfix/), have you tried changing the USB interface to bulk endpoints as specified [here](http://reconstructme.net/2012/10/13/asus-xtion-usb-3-0-hotfix/#comment-754981532) or [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/61211/problem-with-xtion-pro-live-and-openni_camera/?answer=61212#post-id-61212)? Quote from the first link:

> "To get the device working I used OpenNI Unstable 1.5.4.0 (https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI.git) and PrimeSense Sensor Unstable 5.1.2.1 (https://github.com/PrimeSense/Sensor.git)"

> "After installing the driver it is necessary to change the "USB interface" that is used to BULK endpoints by uncommenting UsbInterface=2 in GlobalDefaults.ini (/usr/etc/primesense/GlobalDefaults.ini). I've also found it works when the interface is set to 0. The following comment from the file explains the meaning of the parameters:
> ; USB interface to be used. 0 - FW Default, 1 - ISO endpoints, 2 - BULK endpoints. Default: Arm - 2, other platforms - 1"

---

Originally posted by [timm](https://answers.ros.org/users/6556/timm/) with karma: 376 on 2013-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dyna](https://answers.ros.org/users/6566/dyna/) on 2013-09-10**:
Yeap, I did this....

**Comment by [Keerthi Raj](https://answers.ros.org/users/8061/keerthi-raj/) on 2013-12-01**:
Does this workaround works for Primesense Carmine 1.09?

**Comment by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) on 2014-02-18**:
@timm: Thank you a lot, I resolved it

**Comment by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on 2015-02-20**:
helped - thx!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem for OpenNi2

I had to change
/etc/openni2/PS1080.ini
and set
USBInterface = 0

---

Originally posted by [blizzardroi](https://answers.ros.org/users/13711/blizzardroi/) with karma: 31 on 2014-03-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3